# Apply Texture To Each Side Of Cube Independently?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, away3d, molehill, stage3d

Using Away3D, I've successfully displayed a cube. So far, if I want to display a texture on each side of the cube independently (different textures on each side), I'd have to put them all in one texture, kind of like a sprite map. Is there a way I can do this so I can apply a different bitmap to each side of the cube? Here's my code so far:

```
[Embed(source = "texture.png")] private static var _texture:Class;
var texture:Bitmap = new _texture();
cube = new Cube(new BitmapMaterial(texture.bitmapData),240,240,240);
cube.material.smooth = true;
cube.material.mipmap = (texture.width == texture.height);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try searching for [SkyBox6](http://away3d.com/livedocs/fp10/Away3DLite/away3dlite/primitives/Skybox6.html) or cubic environment mapping.